# Tic Tac Toe game - How to not have results print after invalid entry

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, output

Okay so right now when I try to determine valid input to play again, it will display the results of the game again right after displaying invalid entry and then ask the user to again enter "y" or "n" . I have uploaded a picture to show you. I cannot figure it out for the life of me.

Here is the image:
http://imgur.com/SRsMo4P

```
// GAME OVER
// ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      while (bGameOver)
      {
            // Display game board - PRINT
            for (int i = 0; i<ROW; ++i)
            {
                cout << " " << board[i][0] << " | " << board[i][1] << " | " << board[i][2] << endl;
                if (i==0 || i==1)
                {
                    cout << " - + - + -" << endl;
                }
            }

            // Player wins - OUTPUT
            if(bWinGame)
            {
                cout << endl;
                cout << " Player "<< playerTurn << " wins! HOORAH! " << endl << endl;
                cout << " Written by: Karolina Sabat - CPSC 1103 - Section: S11" << endl << endl;
            }

            // Play again - OUTPUT & USER INPUT
            //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            // VARIABLES
            char again;         // Play again = "Y" or "N"
            cout << endl;
            cout << " Want to play again? ( Y / N )" << endl << endl;
            cout << " "; cin >> again; cout << endl;

            // Play again - if YES        
            if (again == 'y' || again == 'Y')
            {
                bGameOver=false;        // Reset game state
                bWinGame=true;          // Reset assumption

                board[0][0] = '*';      // Rest game board - Array
                board[0][1] = '*';
                board[0][2] = '*';
                board[1][0] = '*';
                board[1][1] = '*';
                board[1][2] = '*';
                board[2][0] = '*';
                board[2][1] = '*';
                board[2][2] = '*';
            }

            // Play again - if NO
            else if (again == 'n' || again == 'N')
            {
                cout << " Awe oh well, thanks for playing. " << endl << endl;
                cout << " Written by: Karolina Sabat - CPSC 1103 - Section: S11" << endl << endl;
                break;
            }

            else
            {
                cout << " INVALID ENTRY: Please input \"Y\" or \"N\" " << endl << endl;
            }
      }

      // Game play continue
      if (!bGameOver)
      {
          // Switch player turn
          if (playerTurn == 1)
          {
              playerTurn = 2;
          }

          else
          {
              playerTurn = 1;
          }

      }  

}



cout << " "; return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have no `break` in this `else` statement:

```
else
{
    cout << " INVALID ENTRY: Please input \"Y\" or \"N\" " << endl << endl;
}
```

The code will continue to run without a `break`, causing strange behavior. Try this:

```
else
{
    cout << " INVALID ENTRY: Please input \"Y\" or \"N\" " << endl << endl;
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Put your input validation code in loop. If Y or N is chosen break the loop.

**P.S.** Add coorrections in code, `break;` is in the wrigth place now.

```
// GAME OVER
// ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      while (bGameOver)
      {
            // Display game board - PRINT
            for (int i = 0; i<ROW; ++i)
            {
                cout << " " << board[i][0] << " | " << board[i][1] << " | " << board[i][2] << endl;
                if (i==0 || i==1)
                {
                    cout << " - + - + -" << endl;
                }
            }

            // Player wins - OUTPUT
            if(bWinGame)
            {
                cout << endl;
                cout << " Player "<< playerTurn << " wins! HOORAH! " << endl << endl;
                cout << " Written by: Karolina Sabat - CPSC 1103 - Section: S11" << endl << endl;
            }

            // Play again - OUTPUT & USER INPUT
            //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            // VARIABLES

            bool bInvalidInput = true;
            while(bInvalidInput)
            {
                    char again;         // Play again = "Y" or "N"
                    cout << endl;
                    cout << " Want to play again? ( Y / N )" << endl << endl;
                    cout << " "; cin >> again; cout << endl;

                    // Play again - if YES        
                    if (again == 'y' || again == 'Y')
                    {
                        bGameOver=false;        // Reset game state
                        bWinGame=true;          // Reset assumption
                        bInvalidInput = false; //stop dialog

                        board[0][0] = '*';      // Rest game board - Array
                        board[0][1] = '*';
                        board[0][2] = '*';
                        board[1][0] = '*';
                        board[1][1] = '*';
                        board[1][2] = '*';
                        board[2][0] = '*';
                        board[2][1] = '*';
                        board[2][2] = '*';
                    }

                    // Play again - if NO
                    else if (again == 'n' || again == 'N')
                    {
                        cout << " Awe oh well, thanks for playing. " << endl << endl;
                        cout << " Written by: Karolina Sabat - CPSC 1103 - Section: S11" << endl << endl;
                        bInvalidInput = false; //stop dialog
                        // break; //need no more
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        cout << " INVALID ENTRY: Please input \"Y\" or \"N\" " << endl << endl;
                    }
            }
            if (bGameOver == true)
            {
                    break; //get here only if bInvalidInput is false and N pressed
            }
      }

      // Game play continue
      if (!bGameOver)
      {
          // Switch player turn
          if (playerTurn == 1)
          {
              playerTurn = 2;
          }

          else
          {
              playerTurn = 1;
          }

      }  

}
```

Comment: I cannot get this to work, it does not accept my input.

Comment: Please check the braces. Have you get this string in console `" Want to play again? ( Y / N )"`

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the sections labelled `Display game board - PRINT` and `Player wins - OUTPUT` outside of (before) the `while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the suggestions but for some reason they were not working properly so I ended up doing this here is the completed code:

```
// FILE: Tic Tac Toe.cpp
// PROGRAMMER: Karolina Sabat   CPSC 1103   Section: S11

// ~~ TWO PLAYER TIC TAC TOE GAME ~~
// Asks the users (player 1, followed by player 2) to select a row and column by 
entering the corresponding row and column number.
// The program will substitute the player's selection with either an "X" or "O".
// A horizontal, vertical or diagonal row of either X's or O's results in a win or 
otherwise game ends in a draw. 
// For subsequent plays, player 1 and player 2 alternate going first. 

#include<iostream>              // For cin, cout
using namespace std;

// MAIN FUNCTION
int main()
{
// VARIABLES
int playerTurn = 1;                         // Player's turn - Player 1
const int ROW=3;                            // Table - Number of rows - For array
const int COL=3;                            // Table - Number of columns - For array
bool bGameOver= false;                      // Game state - True = Game over, False = Continue play
char again;                                 // Play again = "Y" or "N"
char board[ROW][COL] = { {'*', '*', '*'},
                         {'*', '*', '*'},
                         {'*', '*', '*'} }; // Game board - Array


// TITLE
cout << endl;
cout << " TIC TAC TOE" << endl;
cout << " ____________________________________________________" << endl;
cout << " A two player game." << endl;
cout << endl;

// Game state = Continue play - Game is NOT over.
// ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
// Continue play - LOOP
while (!bGameOver)
{
      // Game board - Array - PRINT
      for (int i = 0; i < ROW; ++i)
      {
          cout << " " << board[i][0] <<" | " << board[i][1] <<" | " << board[i][2] << endl;
          if (i==0 || i==1)
          {
                  cout << " - + - + -" << endl;
          }
      }

      // Set player mark ( "X" or "O" )
      // VARIABLES
      char playerMark;
      if (playerTurn == 1)          // Player 1 = "X"
      {
          playerMark = 'X';     
      }
      else
      {
          playerMark = 'O';         // Player 2 = "O"
      }

      // Player move - USER INPUT
      // VARIABLES
      int move_r;                   // Row position - USER INPUT
      int move_c;                   // Column position - USER INPUT
      bool validMove = false;       // Bool ValidMove - Assume false 
      cout << endl;
      cout << " Player " << playerTurn << " , please pick a row and column to place "<< playerMark << "." << endl;
      cout << " Separate the row and column number with a space and press ENTER." << endl;

      while (!validMove) // DETERMINE VALIDITY - Check play move entries
      {
          validMove = true;
          cout << endl;
          cout << " "; cin >> move_r >> move_c; cout << endl;
          // Row 1, Column 1  
          if(move_r == 1 && move_c == 1 && board[0][0] == '*')
          {
              board[0][0] = playerMark;
          }
          // Row 1, Column 2 
          else if(move_r == 1 && move_c == 2 && board[0][1] == '*')
          {
              board[0][1] = playerMark;
          }
          // Row 1, Column 3 
          else if(move_r == 1 && move_c == 3 && board[0][2] == '*')
          {
              board[0][2] = playerMark;
          }
          // Row 2, Column 1 
          else if(move_r == 2 && move_c == 1 && board[1][0] == '*')
          {
              board[1][0] = playerMark;
          }
          // Row 2, Column 2 
          else if(move_r == 2 && move_c == 2 && board[1][1] == '*')
          {
              board[1][1] = playerMark;
          }
          // Row 2, Column 3 
          else if(move_r == 2 && move_c == 3 && board[1][2] == '*')
          {
              board[1][2] = playerMark;
          } 
          // Row 3, Column 1 
          else if(move_r == 3 && move_c == 1 && board[2][0] == '*')
          {
              board[2][0] = playerMark;
          } 
          // Row 3, Column 2 
          else if(move_r == 3 && move_c == 2 && board[2][1] == '*')
          {
              board[2][1] = playerMark;
          }
          // Row 3, Column 3 
          else if(move_r == 3 && move_c == 3 && board[2][2] == '*')
          {
              board[2][2] = playerMark;

          } 

          // INVALID ENTRY
          else 
          {
              cout << " Invalid Move, please try again!" << endl << endl;
              // Will clear characters
              cin.clear();
              cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
              validMove = false;
          }

      }
      // Check if game over conditions are met
      // ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      // If row 0 or column 0 = same playerMark
      if (board[0][0] != '*')
      {
            if (board[0][0] == board[0][1] && board[0][0] == board[0][2])   // Check row 0
            {
                bGameOver=true;
            }
            if (board[0][0] == board[1][0] && board[0][0] == board[2][0])   // Check column 0
            {
                bGameOver=true;
            }
      }

      // If row 1 or column 1 = same playerMark
      if (board[1][1] != '*')
      {

            if(board[1][1] == board[1][0] && board[1][1] == board[1][2])    // Check row 1
            {
                bGameOver=true;
            }

              if(board[1][1] == board[0][1] && board[1][1] == board[2][1])  // Check column 1
            {
                bGameOver=true;
            }

            if(board[1][1] == board[0][0] && board[1][1] == board[2][2])    // Diagonals - Check if 1,1 and 3,3 are equal to 2,2
            {
                bGameOver=true;
            }
            if(board[1][1] == board[2][0] && board[1][1] == board[0][2])    // Diagnonals - Check if 1,3 and 3,1 are equal to 2,2
            {
                bGameOver=true;
            }
      }

      // If row 2 or column 2 = same playerMark
      if (board[2][2] != '*')
      {
            if (board[2][2] == board[2][1] && board[2][2] == board[2][0])   // Check row 2
            {
                bGameOver=true;
            }
            if (board[2][2] == board[1][2] && board[2][2] == board[0][2])   // Check column 2
            {
                bGameOver=true;
            }
      }

      // Check if DRAW
      bool bWinGame=true; // ASSUMPTION - A player won
      if (board[0][0] !='*' && board[0][1] !='*' && board[0][2] !='*' && 
          board[1][0] !='*' && board[1][1] !='*' && board[1][2] !='*' &&
          board[2][0] !='*' && board[2][1] !='*' && board[2][2] !='*' && !bGameOver)
      {
          bGameOver=true;
          bWinGame=false;
          // Tie - OUTPUT
          cout << " Oh, won't you look at that, it's a TIE!"<< endl << endl;
          cout << " Written by: Karolina Sabat - CPSC 1103 - Section: S11" << endl << endl;
      }

      // GAME OVER
      // ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      while (bGameOver)
      {
            // Display game board - PRINT
            for (int i = 0; i<ROW; ++i)
            {
                cout << " " << board[i][0] << " | " << board[i][1] << " | " << board[i][2] << endl;
                if (i==0 || i==1)
                {
                    cout << " - + - + -" << endl;
                }
            }

            // Player wins - OUTPUT
            if(bWinGame)
            {
                cout << endl;
                cout << " Player "<< playerTurn << " wins! HOORAH! " << endl << endl;
                cout << " Written by: Karolina Sabat - CPSC 1103 - Section: S11" << endl << endl;
            }

            // Play again - OUTPUT & USER INPUT
            //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            // VARIABLES
            bool bValidInput = false;

            while (bValidInput != true)
            {

                cout << endl;
                cout << " Want to play again? ( Y / N )" << endl << endl;
                cout << " ";
                // Will clear characters
                cin.clear();
                cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
                cin >> again; cout << endl;

                // Play again - if YES        
                if (again == 'y' || again == 'Y')
                {
                    bValidInput = true;
                    bGameOver=false;        // Reset game state
                    bWinGame=true;          // Reset assumption


                    board[0][0] = '*';      // Rest game board - Array
                    board[0][1] = '*';
                    board[0][2] = '*';
                    board[1][0] = '*';
                    board[1][1] = '*';
                    board[1][2] = '*';
                    board[2][0] = '*';
                    board[2][1] = '*';
                    board[2][2] = '*';
                }

                // Play again - if NO
                else if (again == 'n' || again == 'N')
                {
                    bValidInput = true; // Assumes 
                    cout << " Awe oh well, thanks for playing. " << endl << endl;
                    cout << " Written by: Karolina Sabat - CPSC 1103 - Section: S11" << endl << endl;
                    cout << " "; return 0;
                }

                // Play again - INVALID ENTRY
                else
                {
                    cout << " INVALID ENTRY: Please input \"Y\" or \"N\" " << endl << endl;
                    bValidInput = false;
                }
            }   

      }

      // Game play continue
      if (!bGameOver)
      {
          // Switch player turn
          if (playerTurn == 1)
          {
              playerTurn = 2;
          }

          else
          {
              playerTurn = 1;
          }

      }  

}

// EXIT PROGRAM
 cout << " "; return 0;
}
```

Comment: Actually this does not fix the problem entirely, I have to input yes or no twice, WHY? and the method nondefaultname suggested didn't work.